# Switching to Amazon CDN from dj-static with django on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, amazon-s3

I have been developing a django site on Heroku and using dj-static in my wsgi.py.  I am now about to move my site static files onto Amazon.  Do I need to now remove the references to dj-static from my wsgi.py file?  I'm concerned about the following lines of code.  What would be the correct thing to do?  Do they need to go?  If so, what do I put in their place?:

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from dj_static import Cling

application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```

Thanks,

Euan

Comment: Even I can't answer your question, I guess these links could help:
http://blog.doismellburning.co.uk/2012/07/14/using-amazon-s3-to-host-your-django-static-files/
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3

Answer (score 0):

If you are serving files using `django-storages` you don't need to use `dj-static` anymore. `dj-static` is only used when you want to serve the static files using a WSGI server like `gunicorn`. In your case you are using Amazon's servers.

To answer your question, you can revert to the default `wsgi.py` file which looks something like this:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

You can also remove `dj-static` from your `virtualenv` and from `requirements.txt`